# Where is folder of temporary files from root in OpenBSD?

Tags: unix, filesystems, openbsd, maven

Ive Been using a Test Environment with OpenBSD, NetBeans and Wildfly on localhost with root User.
After pulling some Maven dependencies ive got a full File System on /
and Message that my temporary File folder ist Not big enough to Download all dependencies.

/tmp mount point cleaned Up and doesnt helped.

Any Impressionen? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:
Checked Up $TMPDIR, /tmp and /var/tmp.
After looking in $HOME i have cleaned $HOME/.cache file and had no full File System anymore.

Best wishes